# Intercepting NSMenu key events

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsmenu

I am making a search field, which opens a NSMenu similar to Finder and Mail

The only problem, which drives me crazy, is that i cannot intercept the key events, once the menu is open

- I even subclassed the NSApplication sendEvent, but was surprised to find out, that during menu, there is no call to Applications sendAction:
- I subclassed performKeyEquivalent: NSMenu but it is not called

```
 - (BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

- I am listening for the delegate call on menuHasKeyEquivalent: but it doesn't get called

```
 - (BOOL)menuHasKeyEquivalent:(NSMenu*)menu forEvent:(NSEvent*)event target:(id*)target action:(SEL*)action
```

[image]

How to intercept the keyboard input during NSMenu

Comment: KeyEquivalent is for menu shortcuts not intercepting all the keys, and only works on application's menu bar. I believe making a custom window instead of NSMenu would be a better approach.
Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070492/nstextfield-nsmenu-and-first-responder

Comment: Peter, can you share with us your solution?

Comment: I did up not using NSMenu as i found several problems with this approach... for now i didnt found time to make this into reusable code that can be shared, maybe i will come back to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyEquivalent` is for menu shortcuts not intercepting all the keys. There is no need to intercept the `NSMenu` events and it is not possible to be used for that purpose. To make a suggestion box you basically need to make a custom `NSWindow` and make it look like a menu.

Apple provides a [Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CustomMenus/Introduction/Intro.html) and they explained it in [WWDC 2010 session 145](http://asciiwwdc.com/2010/sessions/145) at some point.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible with a usage of Carbon event handlers. These functions allow interception of keyboard events while menu is open: `GetEventDispatcherTarget()` and `InstallEventHandler()`. This is a hack, but in fact, it works reliably across all MacOSX versions starting from 10.7. Here's the source code that could be used as a reference implementation: https://github.com/mikekazakov/MGKMenuWithFilter